# Sending a HTTP Post from magento 1.6 after customer registration?

Tags: http, magento, http-post

can anyone point me in the right direction I need to send a HTTP post when a customer registers and or makes a purchase from Magento to a third part server ?

It will be the basic information like name, address, postcode , email ect.

Not sure where to start ?

Many thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
$client = new Varien_Http_Client('http://www.example.com/');
$client->setMethod(Varien_Http_Client::POST);
$client->setParameterPost('name', $name);
$client->setParameterPost('address', $address);
//more parameters
try{
    $response = $client->request();
    if ($response->isSuccessful()) {
        echo $response->getBody();
    }
} catch (Exception $e) {
}
```

Comment: sorry for the delay in replying , where do i put this code ? how does this code determine that it is a new customer, could i make a module and attach it to a dispatch evet like:  Mage::dispatchEvent('customer_register_success',
                        array('account_controller' => $this, 'customer' => $customer)
                    );     many thanks for your help...

Comment: Absolutely. For more on event handling, take a look at http://alanstorm.com/magento_config

Comment: thanks will check it out , where would i put it if it was not attached to an event ?

Comment: The only way would be to modify the code in the Customer controller, which is in the 'core' folder. **Never** edit code in the core folder. The only way you really want to do this is with an observer.